# Java proxy connect with another upstream authenticated proxy

Tags: java, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need a fast speed java code to create multiple proxy in one machine get all requests in port:xxxx and send it through an other upstream proxy in example.com:yyyy that needs authentication with username and passwor

I have a proxy multi thread code but how to set Authentication for it ?

```
 public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
            byte[] reply = new byte[4096];
            final InputStream inFromClient = sClient.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream outToClient = sClient.getOutputStream();
            Socket client = null, server = null;
            // connects a socket to the server
            try {
                server = new Socket(SERVER_URL, SERVER_PORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        outToClient));
                out.flush();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            // a new thread to manage streams from server to client (DOWNLOAD)
            final InputStream inFromServer = server.getInputStream();
            final OutputStream outToServer = server.getOutputStream();
            // a new thread for uploading to the server
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    int bytes_read;
                    try {
                        while ((bytes_read = inFromClient.read(request)) != -1) {
                            outToServer.write(request, 0, bytes_read);
                            outToServer.flush();
                            //TODO CREATE YOUR LOGIC HERE
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        outToServer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            // current thread manages streams from server to client (DOWNLOAD)
            int bytes_read;
            try {
                while ((bytes_read = inFromServer.read(reply)) != -1) {
                    outToClient.write(reply, 0, bytes_read);
                    outToClient.flush();
                    //TODO CREATE YOUR LOGIC HERE
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (server != null) {
                        server.close();
                    }
                    if (client != null) {
                        client.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            outToClient.close();
            sClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I can not set system.proxy.host because it use with another program

I need some new approach or code to do something like my code + ability to connect to upstream proxy with authentication, like this pseudo code :

```
final InputStream inFromClient = sClient.getInputStream(Proxy(host,post,username,password));
```